# CORS with Node.js Express running as Windows Service with NSSM

Tags: windows, node.js, express

When I run `node app.js` myself, I do not get a CORS error in the browser. When I run it as a service, I do not get the error on the OPTIONS request, but I do get the error on the POST request.

I created the service using nssm. I configured the service to log in with the same account I use to run the node process.

```js
var express = require('express');
// The `socket` module initializes socket.io for other endpoints
var io = require('./modules/socket');
var upload = require('./routes/upload');

var app = express();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid'}));
});
app.set('port', 5000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.all('/up', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://####.###');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

    if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
      res.send(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
});
app.post('/up', upload.upload);
```

Can you think of a reason why the error on POST will only occur when it is running as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. When creating the service with NSSM, the Startup Directory needed to be the location of the app's main javascript file, not the node executable's location.

It looks like it was permissions problem when writing to disk.